# How to set ListView selected item alternet text color in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom listview with a imageview and an textview. I want when user select a item the textview color should change and all the other textview should remain default.

here are my xmls

### ListView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewBell"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### ListViewItems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_bell_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/rihanna_love_the_way_lie"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_bell_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/bronze_bell" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create following button_text.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Change your text view's textColor to:

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_bell_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/rihanna_love_the_way_lie"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text" //point to that xml
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />
```

You can read about color state list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: The following code works for me: `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>`

Comment: the file needs to be in res/color, not res/drawable

Answer (score 5):

Like others have said, just change the color in your onItemClick method.  Additionally:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);


        setItemNormal();
        View rowView = view;
        setItemSelected(rowView);

    }

public void setItemSelected(View view){
    View rowView = view;
    TextView tv = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}

public void setItemNormal()
{
    for (int i=0; i< mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);
        //TextView txtview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menurow_title));
        TextView txtview = ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1));
        txtview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

by doing this we set all items to normal before we change it on each item press.

Comment: That's a bad practice to have to iterate through all items on every tap. Just use the built in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

For that you've to set OnClickListener for that particular ImageView and then change TextView's color on click of ImageView in Adapter Class.
Alternatively,

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            TextView tv= view.findViewById(resID); 
            tv.setTextColor(color)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `setOnItemClickListener` for the listView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.getParent();
            TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
            ImageView imaegView = (ImageView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);

            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
           // Perform whatever action for your textView and imageView


        }

    });
```

Comment: but how to change the others item to default color

Answer (score 0):

after many attempts set color in navigation view, I found out the simplest way to set text color in listview, maybe it will help to someone

**res/color/listview_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- This is used when the navigation item is selected -->
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <!-- This is the default text color -->
    <item
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

and set in **TextView** as **android:textColor**:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_extra_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/listview_selector"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="Row item text" />
```

the trouble was in the right state, use **android:state_activated** in navigation view