# Selected ListView item doesn't change text color even with ColorStateList resource assigned

Tags: android, listview

I want the text color of an item in a ListView to change when selected. I read the following post ([How to set ListView selected item alternet text color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451996/how-to-set-listview-selected-item-alternet-text-color-in-android)) and made the following changes:

Created a ColorStateList resource @drawable/list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="#ffffff00" /> <!-- default -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:color="#ff000000" />
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:color="#ffff0000" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="#ff0000ff" />
```

Assigned the resource to textColor attribute in the target TextView

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/person_active_list_name"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/person_list_name_left_padding"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/person_list_image_size"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/person_active_thumbnail"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/person_active_list_arrow"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/person_active_thumbnail"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/person_active_list_arrow"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:textColor="@drawable/list_item" />
```

For some reason, only the default color in @drawable/list_item.xml is applied (so the ColorStateList resource is indeed being consumed by the TextView). There is no change, however, in text color when a list item is pressed, selected, etc. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Note: Remember that the first item in the state list that matches the current state of the object will be applied. So if the first item in the list contains none of the state attributes above, then it will be applied every time, which is why your default value should always be last

So, change your definition to this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#ff000000" />

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#ffff0000" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="#ff0000ff" />

    <item android:color="#ffffff00" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: ah, thank you for pointing this out to me! I simply didn't read the full documentation, silly me. It's working now, much appreciated. Also, for anyone else who runs into this, my particular case needed to use state_activated="true" instead of state_selected="true".